# how to access a server through url instead of ip address inside of a running container

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I have a running debian container, inside the container, I can ping a server through its ip, something like this:

```
ping 9.1.1.1
```

but if I do this:

```
ping fileserver01
```

it will generate errors, saying it is not accessible.

But both them work just fine in the host computer (ubuntu). Anything I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What maps the name `fileserver01` to an IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix is to use `--add-host` while docker run OR `extra_hosts` if you are using compose -

For instance -

`docker run -it --add-host fileserver01:9.1.1.1 debian ....`

It will put a host entry in your `/etc/hosts` -

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-186:~$ sudo docker run -it --add-host fileserver01:9.1.1.1 debian bash -c "cat /etc/hosts ; ping fileserver01"
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
9.1.1.1 fileserver01
172.17.0.4  23f2df5d9b24

  PING fileserver01 (9.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    ^C
    --- fileserver01 ping statistics ---
    8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6999ms
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new container, that will be in the default bridge network.

Bridge network by not have the DNS server by default.

you can do two things :

1.) Have the container in the default Bridge network and use the --link option to manually configure containers to know each other.

```
docker run -d -P --name <container1> --link <container2>
```

2.) Creating a new network and while creating the container use --network option.

```
docker run -d --name <container_name> --network <network_name>
```

Containers in the same network can interact with referring to the container name instead of the IP address.

```
docker container exec -it <container1_name> ping <container2_name>
```

--link is the legacy option so that can be removed in the feature.

> This is for recognition of container by other container.

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: if you want to access a external server then you need to configure the known host with the alias name and the respective ip address.